# How can I insert a disclaimer in a Wordpress site?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to look for a way to enable me to insert a disclaimer into the footer of my website. I am using wordpress to power my website.
Is there anyway I can make a page link at the bottom?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Disclaimer</a>
```

Comment: You mean you want to add `Disclaimer` as menu link in footer?

Comment: We are not here to teach you from scratch. You'll have to read and practice a lot: the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org), [WPTuts+](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/) and [wordpress.se]. And for any Stack site: [About] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit your theme's footer.php and include an anchor tag wherever you like.

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/page-you-want-to-link-to">Click here to see the disclaimer</a>
```